# Android WebView open external link in browser

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview, target

I'm learning programming on android , does anyone know how I could do to open links to the different default browser on my domain?

If someone would be kind enough to explain to me how I could also create a menu for the page refresh and an alert indicating that the missing internet connection.

```
// *********************************MainActivity.java***************************
package com.infser.venditelo.com;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // set your custom url here
    String url = "http://www.venditelo.com";

    // if you want to show progress bar on splash screen
    Boolean showProgressOnSplashScreen = true;

    WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar prgs;
    RelativeLayout splash, main_layout;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        prgs = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        // splash screen View
        if (!showProgressOnSplashScreen)
            ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarSplash)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);

//      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
//
//          // get status bar height to push webview below that
//          int result = 0;
//          int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
//                  "dimen", "android");
//          if (resourceId > 0) {
//              result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
//          }
//
//          // set top padding to status bar
//          main_layout.setPadding(0, result, 0, 0);
//      }

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        // control javaScript and add html5 features
        mWebView.setFocusable(true);
        mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(
                this.getFilesDir().getPath() + this.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/");

        // this force use chromeWebClient
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);


                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // check if splash is still there, get it away!
                if (splash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // slideToBottom(splash);

            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * To animate view slide out from top to bottom
     * 
     * @param view
     */
    // void slideToBottom(View view) {
    // TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0,
    // view.getHeight());
    // animate.setDuration(2000);
    // animate.setFillAfter(true);
    // view.startAnimation(animate);
    // view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }



}




// *********************************AndroidManifest.xml***************************

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.infser.venditelo.com"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> <!--ROTAZIONE SCHERMO DISABILITATA-->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

### If You open HTML or URL in Deafulat Browser Used TextView

### For HTML

String value = "Visit my blog http://www.maxartists.com\">mysite View myactivity callback";

```
String value = "<html>Visit my blog <a href=\"http://www.maxartists.com\">mysite</a> View <a href=\"sherif-activity://myactivity?author=sherif&nick=king\">myactivity</a> callback</html>";
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(value));
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

### For URL

```
tv.setText("www.google.com  www.facebook.com  www.yahoo.com");
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());;
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(tv.getText().toString()));
Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score 0):

> All links other than "String url" will be opened on the browsers default, not in WebApp. –  Davide Infsercom just now   edit